# How to execute custom loop before loop content?

Tags: loop

How to execute custom loop before loop content?

```
<?php

    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_open', 5 );
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_close', 15 );
    add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'gt_custom_loop');

    function gt_custom_loop() {

        // this gets executed after the page content, how to make it execute before?

    }

    genesis();

?>
```

Comment: This seems specific to Genesis and might be better aimed at their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the genesis_before_content hook.

```
add_action('genesis_before_content', 'gt_custom_loop');
function gt_custom_loop() {

    // this gets executed after the page content, how to make it execute before?

}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually what I was looking for was to insert the HTML after the header, but I believe both would do the trick. Thanks.